# Как по дате оптеределить последний день месяца?

Tags: javascript

Если последний день месяца вернуть `true`, иначе `false`

Если есть возможность предложите пожалуйства вариант определения без создания отдельной функции

```js
function isLastDate () {

}

console.log( isLastDate('2023-05-29') ); // return false
console.log( isLastDate('2023-05-31') ); // return true
```

> Пометили как дубликат, хотя там другой вопрос

Решил вопрос таким способом

```js
function isLastDate (date) {
  return new Date(new Date(date).getFullYear(), new Date(date).getMonth() + 1, 0).toLocaleDateString() === new Date(date).toLocaleDateString();
}

console.log( isLastDate('2023-05-29') ); // return false
console.log( isLastDate('2023-05-31') ); // return true
```

Comment: **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос**. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу. Подробнее [в справке](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).